# Raid 1 and Owncloud

Tags: server, hard-drive, data-transfer, owncloud

I have done a Raid 1 system using 2 external HD connected to the Pi2, now I want to install owncloud in the raspberry using the raid to avoid losses, using the external HD connected to store the data.

The problem is that I cannot mount the Hd due this error:

```
> mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

Also when I do the fdisk -l command this is the result:

```
Device         Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1         8192  2437500  2429309  1.2G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      2437501 31291391 28853891 13.8G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      2441216  2506749    65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6      2506752  2635775   129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7      2637824 31291391 28653568 13.7G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000590401536 bytes, 732566016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00029ee8

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         256 732566015 732565760  2.7T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000590401536 bytes, 732566016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00029ee8

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         256 732566015 732565760  2.7T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 2.7 TiB, 3000455135232 bytes, 732532992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

My main doubt is how can I create a folder owncloud inside the external HD, I researched but there is not many information about Raid. I have not installed owncloud yet, because I want to do this part before. Maybe someone have tried this before and can give me some advice to do it.

Also I want to know if this is worthty, or it is better to have a single HD connected and store it there, due the speed, because maybe the Pi is not ready for Raid system and webservers together.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't set up RAID specifically on the Pi, I have set up RAID on Linux and haven't run into the problem that you're encountering.

Have you formatted the md0 partition? If not, that would explain the specific error that you're encountering.

Once you do that, you'll mount /dev/md0 to the owncloud/data directory, and any data that you upload to owncloud will be written to the array.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID has lots of information on how to assemble an array using mdadm.